# Help with arduino float

Tags: code-review, coding-standards

I am having trouble with this code:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <MPU6050.h>

MPU6050 mpu;

// Timers
unsigned long timer = 0;
float timeStep = 0.01;

// Pitch, Roll and Yaw values
float pitch = 0;
float roll = 0;
float yaw = 0;

int button_pin=5;
int button_state;
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Initialize MPU605  
  while(mpu.begin(MPU6050_SCALE_2000DPS, MPU6050_RANGE_2G))
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid MPU6050 sensor, check wiring!");
    delay(500);
  }

  // Calibrate gyroscope. The calibration must be at rest.
  // If you don't want calibrate, comment this line.
  mpu.calibrateGyro();

  // Set threshold sensivty. Default 3.
  // If you don't want use threshold, comment this line or set 0.
  mpu.setThreshold(3);

  pinmode(button_pin,INPUT)
}

void loop()
{
  int button_state=digitalRead(button_pin)

  timer = millis();

  // Read normalized values
  Vector norm = mpu.readNormalizeGyro();

  // Calculate Pitch, Roll and Yaw
  pitch = pitch + norm.YAxis * timeStep;
  roll = roll + norm.XAxis * timeStep;
  yaw = yaw + norm.ZAxis * timeStep;

  // Output raw
  Serial.print(" Pitch = ");
  Serial.print(pitch);
  Serial.print(" Roll = ");
  Serial.print(roll);  
  Serial.print(" Yaw = ");
  Serial.println(yaw);

  // Wait to full timeStep period
  delay((timeStep*1000) - (millis() - timer));
}
```

But when I add this code at the end:

```cpp
If (pitch <=90 && pitch => 15 && button_state =(HIGH))
{
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

I know the issue is about the pitch part of the if. I just need to know how to fix it.

Comment: The if-statement should be `if` not `If`

Comment: Could you please post the error that you are getting.

Comment: also `button_state =(HIGH)` should be `button_state == HIGH` or more simply `button_state`

Comment: @sa_leinad I get this error (error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment) this iş the error I am getting

Answer (score 1):

You have two declarations of button_state.  This won't cause a problem because the scoping rules will mean inside loop you are using the local one and everywhere else you are using the global one.  Personally I would remove the global one since you aren't using it.

As mentioned in the comments you have mistyped the `If` keyword (but I think this is just on here not in you code) and you have used an assignment statement rather than a equivalence (= instead of ==).

Since you have tagged it as code review here are some minor points you might want to consider.

If a value doesn't change then you could mark it as `const`, this doesn't make much difference to the compiler, it already knows, but it will help you when you come back to the code next week.
  So: `const int button_pin = 5;`

If you only use a `const int` value **once** you might be better `#defining` it (more than once a const value *should* produce smaller code).  The pre-processor (part of the compile process) will replace the defined name with the value, but you have easier to read and maintain code.
  So: `#define button_pin 5`

If you `#define` an int then **always** enclose the value in brackets to protect it from "arithmetic issues" (I can't think of a better way of describing it).
  So: `#define button_pin (5)`

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, but still you haven't told me how to fix the error 

Comment: The solution to your problem was answered by sa_leinad in the comments on you post and is covered in the second paragraph of my answer.  "you have used an assignment statement rather than a equivalence".  If you tell me you IP address I'll remote into your machine and fix your code for you if you like.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed was that you had a capital `I` in your if-statement.

Secondly, `button_state =(HIGH)` should be `button_state == HIGH`. A single `=` sign means that you are assigning a value to the variable on the left - in this case `button_state`. It is a common mistake that I have made many times.

Also, because it is a boolean comparison, you can simplify the statement by removing the `== HIGH` leaving just `button_state`.

This would then change the if-statement to the following:

```
if ((pitch <= 90) && (pitch => 15) && button_state)
```

I have added extra parentheses for clarity/readability but they're technically not needed.

---

In addition to what Code Gorilla has already stated in [his answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/45541/19409) and a few additional semi-colons, your code should look something like this:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <MPU6050.h>

MPU6050 mpu;

// Timers
unsigned long timer = 0;
float timeStep = 0.01;

// Pitch, Roll and Yaw values
float pitch = 0;
float roll = 0;
float yaw = 0;

const int button_pin = 5;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Initialize MPU605  
  while(mpu.begin(MPU6050_SCALE_2000DPS, MPU6050_RANGE_2G))
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid MPU6050 sensor, check wiring!");
    delay(500);
  }

  // Calibrate gyroscope. The calibration must be at rest.
  // If you don't want calibrate, comment this line.
  mpu.calibrateGyro();

  // Set threshold sensivty. Default 3.
  // If you don't want use threshold, comment this line or set 0.
  mpu.setThreshold(3);

  pinmode(button_pin,INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  int button_state = digitalRead(button_pin);

  timer = millis();

  // Read normalized values
  Vector norm = mpu.readNormalizeGyro();

  // Calculate Pitch, Roll and Yaw
  pitch = pitch + norm.YAxis * timeStep;
  roll = roll + norm.XAxis * timeStep;
  yaw = yaw + norm.ZAxis * timeStep;

  // Output raw
  Serial.print(" Pitch = ");
  Serial.print(pitch);
  Serial.print(" Roll = ");
  Serial.print(roll);  
  Serial.print(" Yaw = ");
  Serial.println(yaw);

  if ((pitch <= 90) && (pitch => 15) && button_state)
  {
      // Code goes here
  }

  // Wait to full timeStep period
  delay((timeStep*1000) - (millis() - timer));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the if statement:

```
if (pitch <=90 && pitch => 15 && button_state =(HIGH))
```

you assign a new value to button_state, which is illegal.

This should read:

```
if (pitch <=90 && pitch => 15 && button_state == HIGH)
```

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect. The condition in the first _if_ is parsed as `(pitch <= 90 && pitch => 15 && button_state) = HIGH` (which does not compile), not as `pitch <= 90 && pitch => 15 && (button_state = HIGH)` (which would compile and is what your answer implies). Hence the compile error “_lvalue required as left operand of assignment_”.